# Basic mailchimp workflow - can this be done?

Tags: automation, mailchimp, newsletter

I have just registered a new domain, created a free mailchimp account and do my first steps using the mentioned ESP. I have red through various support articles but am kind of lost on how to achieve my goal...

**Main goal**

Send out a very basic, daily newsletter containing just about two or three sentences, ideally by using the official mailchimp Android app.

**Setup tasks**

- Register and verify senderdomain
- Host subscribtion form using double opt in
- Create a template, list and campaign

**Workflow**

- Choose template-campaign
- Enter "message of the day"
- Click send!!

**Questions**

- Can this be done without extra coding?
- Do I really have create a new campaign for each daily newsletter? I guess not, but what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You do have to create a new campaign for each newsletter, but you can copy previous campaign and start from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a new campaign for each daily newsletter. Fortunately, that is a quick process in Mailchimp.

Answer (score 0):

I found that an RSS-Campaign combined with a Wordpress blog site is the right way to go.